# Make an absolute item show above the relative one?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with the absolute property, I would like to collapse a div to the right of an other relative div, I made it possible but the `absolute` div shows inside the `relative` one. I tried the `z-index` property but it doesn't work. I would like the absolute item to be above everything while being sticked to the relative one but I can't know why it acts like that:

[image]

HTML:

```css
/* PROGRESS BAR */
.footer-progressbar{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

    background: var(--grey);
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.footer-progressbar-bar{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;

    position: relative;

    width: 30%;
    height: 25px;

    padding: 5px 10px;

    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;

    background: var(--main-color);
    border-radius: 100px;

    animation: progress-bar 30s ease-in-out infinite;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.footer-progressbar-bar p{
    text-align: right;

    font-size: 14px;
    text-shadow: 0 0.5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.download-percentage{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;

    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    
    background: #191919;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

.download-percentage span{
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- LOADING PROGRESS -->
<div class="footer-progressbar">
    <div class="footer-progressbar-bar">

        <!-- PROGRESS -->
        <div class="download-percentage">
            <span>100%</span>
        </div>

        <!-- FILES -->
        <p>0/0 (5 GB) - Loading 'Workshop File Name'</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: remove the overflow:hidden?

Comment: So, you want the `<div>` that says 100% to be below the other one?

Comment: Hey @TemaniAfif, yes I want the 100% div to show above the progressbar but keeping it sticked to it

Comment: oh my god, I am so dumb, thank you.....

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I forgot to remove an "overflow: hidden;"
But now I have an other problem:

My `p` text is visible outside the div, how can I hide text overflow without having hide the rest?

[image]